# Only 1 character instead of the whole word being returned in a PHP array after retrieving from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays

In Javascript I'm creating an array for a user side list

```
var dataArr = [];
 $("#sortable li").each(function(idx, elem) {
    dataArr[idx] = $(elem).html();
});
alert(dataArr[0]);
```

This is working as expected and will alert the first item in the list. "Frank" or whatever it may be.

```
$.ajax({
url: "fiddle.php",
type: "POST",
data: "dataArr="+dataArr,
success: function(response) {
alert(response);}
```

I send this array over to PHP and the ajax test confirms its retrieved from a var_dump on the other side.

```
echo ($_POST['dataArr'][1]);
```

The problem occurs here when trying to output a particular item, in this case the 2nd item which may be "John" **it'll instead output the 2nd character in the first item "r"**. This is appearing in the Ajax test window. I'm looking for the whole word instead.
Is it a syntax error or a problem with how the data is passed?

Comment: You're not really sending an array. Either use `console.log("dataArr="+dataArr)`, or use the `var_dump`. You should have noticed that already, or what did the `var_dump` echo for you?

Comment: What is that `dataStr` good for? Did you originally want to send that?

Comment: try using `data:{dataArr:dataArr}`

Comment: var_dump returns string(66) and all the elements listed one after another seperated by a comma. dataStr is for something else, I removed that from the original question.

Comment: You can encode array to JSON on clientside and decode using `json_decode` in PHP

Comment: {dataArr:dataArr} appears to work and output correctly, ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is related to how you are sending your data in the ajax call.

Try this:

## **JS**

```
var dataArr = [];
 $("#sortable li").each(function(idx, elem) {
    dataArr[idx] = $(elem).html();
});


$.ajax({
    url: "fiddle.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: dataArr, //Send just the array
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

## **PHP**

```
var_dump($_POST['dataArr']);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your array is getting converted to string form.

do `JSON.stringify()` at client side and `json_decode` at server side

like

in the ajax call

```
data: "dataArr="+JSON.stringify(dataArr),
```

and in the php code

```
$dataArr = json_encode($_POST['dataArr']);
var_dump($dataArr);
```